# Не получается преобразовать строку в int после парсинга. Java

Tags: java, парсер

Написал код, который парсит температуру с сайта. Потом захотел преобразовать эту температуру в int. Но перепробовав разные функции преобразования, у меня все время выскакивает ошибка. При этом если самому создать String и потом преобразовать в int, то все работает.

Метод для парсинга и преобразования и ошибку прикрепляю ниже:

```
 public int getTemperatureFromGisMeteo() {
    String currentTemperature = "1";
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-novosibirsk-4690/").get();
        String titleElement = document.title();
        Element element = document.getElementsByClass("unit unit_temperature_c").first();
        currentTemperature = element.text();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(currentTemperature);
}
```

Ошибка следующая:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "−22"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at ParsingData.getTemperatureFromGisMeteo(ParsingData.java:22)
at WeatherStation.main(WeatherStation.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В полученной строке в переменной `currentTemperature` не обычный минус, а юникодный ["\u2212"](https://unicode-table.com/ru/2212), `Integer.parseInt` такое не понимает. Для сравнения в строке поиска на сайте https://unicode-table.com введите минус с клавиатуры (получите https://unicode-table.com/ru/002D/) и скопируйте и вставьте минус из текста ошибки (получите https://unicode-table.com/ru/2212/)

Сделайте перед конвертацией в `Integer` замену на обычный минус:

```
return Integer.parseInt(currentTemperature.replace("\u2212", "-")
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!

Comment: У меня только 1 вопрос - КАК? :) Как ваша мысль повернулась в сторону "альтернативных юникодных символов"? Или это следствие неоднократного возникновения подобных ситуаций в проф. деятельности?

Comment: @kami, с различными юникодными символами сталкивался в проекте фанатской локализации одной игры. В игру можно пропатчить только текст в однобайтовой кодировке, а переводчики могут воткнуть и длинные тире, и какие-нибудь хитрые кавычки, или хитрые пробелы (не знаю, из ворда копируют что ли?) Такие символы в однобайтовую кодировку не преобразовываются, приходится чистить. Ну и в целом сталкивался с тем, что от сервисов прилетают какие-нибудь хитрые юникодные символы. Так что просто опыт.

Comment: Да он и визуально на самом деле сильно отличается

Comment: @DiMithras, да, но не в моноширинном шрифте: - − или  `- −`. Когда в терминал выводится можно и не заметить, что какой-то не такой минус.